# My android webview is not loading the page within the webview in the older android version but loads in android 7 or 7.1.1

Tags: java, android, webview

> Please note that the code executes fine in android 7.1.1 but for older versions this problem is arising. When initially i run the app it loads perfectly fine but as soon as i click to external links (not from within the website itself) it opens in the default browser. Please tell me where i am going wrong???
>   Thank ver very much.

```
private class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient {      
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")  
    @Override  
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  
        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("library.cus.ac.in"))
        {  
            return false;  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));  
            startActivity(intent);  
            return true;  
        }  
    }  
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)  
    @Override  
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)   {  
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());  
        return true;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Your problem on older Android Versions, that external URLs are opened with an external Browser, right? That is exactly what you "tell" your Webview in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) `

Comment: Thank you very much for your acknowledgement. Actually i want every url (external or internal) to open within the webview itself for all the android versions. What changes should i make it to accomplish??